# Getting "uninitialized constant CarrierWave::Backgrounder (NameError)" only for some rails commands?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm using [CarrierWave::Backgrounder](https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder) and everything works on `production` as expected. `rails s` also still works in `development` but any other `rails` command (`rails c`, `rails g`, ...) do not work and fail with:

```
/Users/user/Sites/example/app/uploaders/avatar_uploader.rb:4:in `<class:AvatarUploader>': uninitialized constant CarrierWave::Backgrounder (NameError)
```

Did anyone ever have this weird problem?

Comment: have faced such issue but cannot recall; lets see if I remember

Comment: try calling the other commands with `bundle exec` - for example `bundle exec rails c`

Comment: Thanks but I already tried that.

Comment: seems that in some env `app/uploaders` isn't added to autoload path, so just forcely add that line to env file

Comment: Perhaps you need to stop / kill `spring`?